# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE MK_Dosen (
No INT NOT NULL,
Kode CHAR(6),
Kelas CHAR(2),
NIK CHAR(7),
FOREIGN KEY (Kode)
);
```

I have tried and seen the material presented by the lecturer but I still can't find the reason for this syntax error. Can anyone help me?

[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37eZQ.png)

Comment: That's not correct, [learn more about foreign key here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Perhaps, you were trying to [add primary key](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63abfe1fb86bbb172a7677c8be90e076) instead?

Comment: `No` is a reserved word. You could use it if you wrap it in back ticks, but it's a poor choice anyway. Your `FOREIGN KEY` clause is missing the information for the table and field it references.

Comment: ohh, i just tried it and it worked, i didnt insert the reference before, but how i insert 2 references ? I only included one reference.

Comment: you can add multiple FOREIGN keys on another columns like this   `FOREIGN KEY(column1) REFERENCES table2(column3),
  FOREIGN KEY(column2) REFERENCES table3(column4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the foreign key a reference column of others table

ex: table demo and field is field (type shoulde be same with MK_Dosen.Kode)

```
CREATE TABLE MK_Dosen (
  No INT NOT NULL,
  Kode CHAR(6),
  Kelas CHAR(2),
  NIK CHAR(7),
  FOREIGN KEY (Kode) REFERENCES demo(field)
);
```